# Want to know about split() in store procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sageframe

```
DECLARE @timeRange as varchar(max)
SET @timeRange= '00:30-01:00**00:20-01:00'

DECLARE @tblTime TABLE(RowNum int identity(1,1),TimeRange ntext)

INSERT INTO @tblTime SELECT rtrim(ltrim(items)) from split(@timeRange,'**')
select *from @tblTime
```

The above procedure is returning three rows with the middle being null

And

```
DECLARE @timeRange as varchar(max)
SET @timeRange= '00:30-01:00*00:20-01:00'

DECLARE @tblTime TABLE(RowNum int identity(1,1),TimeRange ntext)

INSERT INTO @tblTime SELECT rtrim(ltrim(items)) from split(@timeRange,'*')
select *from @tblTime
```

The above code is returning two rows exactly what I wanted.

I'd like to know why the split() function affects my result.

I have concatenated string with `**` first then split, the result is different from the string concatenated with `*`.
EDITED: the split function is from SageFrame

Comment: What does "split" look like? Why `*` in one and `\*\*` in the other?

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the `\*\*` which I assume should be `**`...

I *guess* (we don't know what the split function looks like) that the delimiter parameter is `char(1)` (or `varchar(1)`). This means that `**` is truncated to `*`, so you get 3 rows.